# jQuery animate causing screen to jump

Tags: jquery

So I'm learning jQuery and I think there is something that I am missing.  I am using the following code on a "div" tag:

`$("#faq-group-notice").animate({ height:'hide', opacity:'hide' });`

It appears to be a final jump when it is finishing the animation.  Any ideas about how to get rid of that?

EDIT: css for the div tag

`<div id="faq-group-notice" class="flash notice hidden"></div>`

`.hidden {
  display: none;
}`

`.notice {padding:0.8em;margin-bottom:1em;border:2px solid #ddd;}`

Comment: @mark s , can you please post css for faq-group-notice

Comment: @mark s is your div position :relative???

Comment: @mark i created a jsfiddle here ,it works fine , i think there is something else wrong http://jsfiddle.net/AepAp/ , can you also try to make a jsfiddle

Comment: @gov Here is the jsfiddle (I didn't even know jsfiddle existed, thanks for that!) http://jsfiddle.net/J7YEH/ - It shows the issue.

Comment: @mark , what is the problem there , you don't want other items to push down , or you want smooth effect while hiding??

Comment: @gov - Sorry about that.  I want the smooth effect when hiding.

Comment: @mark: I see you have some good answers below -- but most of them are more complicated than they need to be.  Please see my answer below for an actual explanation of *why* you were seeing the "jump", and a *simple* fix to go with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [update to your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/J7YEH/6/).

The "jump" is coming from the margin and border that you have put on the div that's being hidden/shown.  The height animation (and also the built-in slide effects) don't account for margin and border.  As a result, the animation runs, (for example, on a "hide") it collapses the *interior* height of the element to zero, then it applies `display:none` -- since the element's margin and border are still visible, the application of `display:none` causes the element to "blip" out of existence.  The opposite happens when you show such an element -- it "blips" into existence, then the *interior* height expands from zero to the original/natural height of the element.

in my adjustment of your jsFiddle (linked above), I have simply added a div that wraps the content you're hiding/showing, and I've moved your css classes `flash` and `notice` to the interior div.  Now, *all* of the visible content (including the margin and border) are *inside* `#faq-group-notice`, so when the height animation effect runs, it collapses *everything* -- not just the stuff inside the border.

Answer (score 2):

@Mark ,

All you want is slideDown and up right , you can use this

```
$("#faq-group-notice").slideDown();
$("#faq-group-notice").slideUp();
```

see jquery api for multiple options

```
http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/
```

Comment: While that's the approach I took myself, there's *still* a noticeable jump after the element's (I *think*) `innerHeight` is reduced to zero and the border is hidden. (Albeit using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` reduces it as far as possible).

Comment: @david , jquery animations has lot of options , i think if we explore tem we can get that smooth effect, i am just trying in fiddle , if i get i will post again.

Comment: That will work.  However, I like the fadeIn combination as well.  Can they be combined?

Comment: @Mark S., almost *everything* in jQuery can be combined, and coupled with callbacks and such. =)

Answer (score 2):

While I think that @gov probably nailed your problem with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359975/jquery-animate-causing-screen-to-jump/4360205#4360205), I choose to offer [this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J7YEH/1/) as a...further suggestion.

This uses the following jQuery:

```
$('#faq-group-notice').slideDown(1000);
$('#faq-group-notice').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0},500).slideUp(500);
    });
```

And requires a user-interaction (which I presume to be your intent in the real use-case) to close the `#faq-group-notice` div.

---

**Edited** with a slightly revised demo, and jQuery:

```
$('#faq-group-notice').slideDown(1000);
$('#faq-group-notice').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0},500,
                        function(){
                            $(this).animate(
                                {
                                    'border-width':0
                                }, 100).slideUp(500);
                        });
    });
```

[Revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J7YEH/3/).

---

**Edited**
Re-revised jQuery, and demo, in response to the OP's comment:

> Actually, this is just a way of sending a bit of information to the user. I would like it to just disappear after a bit of time. Currently, I have the timeout to execute this code to run after 3 secs.

```
$('$('#faq-group-notice').slideDown(1000);
$('#faq-group-notice').delay(3000).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'border-width': 0
    }, 100).slideUp(500);
});
```

[Re-revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J7YEH/7/).

Comment: @David - Actually, this is just a way of sending a bit of information to the user.  I would like it to just disappear after a bit of time.  Currently, I have the timeout to execute this code to run after 3 secs.

Comment: @mark , you can add a jquery; delay which will hide after 3 seconds//something like this slideUp(300).delay(300)

Comment: @gov, thanks! =) @Mark S., please see *re* -revised answer... =)

Comment: @David - Wonderful solution!  I love it!

@gov - thanks for all of your help as well!

Comment: @Mark S., aww, *shucks..!* =p

Comment: @gov, *awesome*, I'm all about the giving back! =p (also, +1 for your own answer, since I, *honestly*, figure your own answer is *at least* as useful as my own).

Answer (score 1):

@gov is right, using one of the slide* methods would probably make more sense for what you're trying to do. However, if you want to `animate()` it yourself then you'll want to animate everything that takes up space including the `margin-bottom`:

```
$("#faq-group-notice").animate({
    height:       '0px',
    marginBottom: '0px',
    padding:      '0px',
    borderWidth:  '0px',
    opacity:      0
}, function() { $(this).remove() });
```

The callback is there just to clean things up at the end. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/w5gVU/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your animation is being called from an `<a href="#">Show ...</a>` tag, remember to return false on the click handler.

Also, if your div has a static position, it will push down all the content below it. To fix that, position it absolutely or relatively, but beware that when it expands it might cover over something else.

Comment: he has jsfiddle example ,and his html is div only.