# .show() causing scrollable DIV to jump to top in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I've got a scrollable `div` with rows (and hidden rows).  Clicking on one of the rows causes the next hidden sibling to show.

In Firefox, however, clicking on a row causes the scrollable `div` to jump back up to the top, and only the first time.  Scroll back down and click a row, and the scrollbar stays where it is.

IE and Chrome do not reset the scrollbar, which is extra frustrating.

http://jsfiddle.net/xyan/TH4X3/

**HTML:**

The HTML is lengthy for the purposes of having enough information to have a scrollbar.  Because of its length, I won't post it here.

**Javascript:**

```
var trackingresults = {
    pos: [],
    container: {},
    data: {}
}
trackingresults.container = $('#test-tracking');
trackingresults.container.delegate('tr:not(.history)', 'click', function() {
    if ($(this).next('tr').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find('td.details').removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
        $(this).removeClass('current');
        $(this).next('tr').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).find('td.details').removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(this).next('tr').show();
    }
    return false;
});
trackingresults.container.delegate('tr:not(.history)', 'hover', function() {
    if ($(this).find('td.details').hasClass('hover')) {
        $(this).find('td').removeClass('hover');
    } else {
        $(this).find('td').addClass('hover');
    }
    return false;
});
```

One of the "Similar Questions" links suggested [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359975/jquery-animate-causing-screen-to-jump).  This seems similar, but might be different enough to warrant this question.

Is there something I can do to prevent the jumping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit and the problem went away:  http://jsfiddle.net/TH4X3/6/

You don't need the `.hover()` handler or the `.hover` class, just do it in css via `:hover`.  Replace this selector: `#test-shipments td.hover` with this:

```css
#test-shipments tr.current, #test-shipments tr:hover td {
    background-color: #B1C3C4;
}
```

You don't need a `.collapsed` class - just make that the default and let `.expanded` override the defaults.

Rather than showing and hiding the next row explicitly, just use css to do it, based on the previous siblings `.expanded` class.  Use the adjacent sibling selector - `+`:

```css
#test-shipments tr.expand + tr.history {
    display: table-row;
}
```

With just those css tweaks* you can reduce your JavaScript to just this:

```js
var trackingresults = {
    pos: [],
    container: {},
    data: {}
}
trackingresults.container = $('#test-tracking');
trackingresults.container.delegate('tr:not(.history)', 'click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
});
```

And as a side-effect, your firefox scrolling issue goes away!

* <sup>Plus a couple of IE7 hacks, see [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TH4X3/6/)</sup>

Comment: Holy crap, thanks for the help with this.  It kills me that I didn't think to use `:hover` before now, especially with just a color change.